# ValueError: too many values to unpack python with wtforms_extended_selectfield

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to incorporate the following code from this [github page](https://github.com/industrydive/wtforms_extended_selectfield/blob/master/wtforms_extended_selectfield.py) into my WTForm project in order to use `optgroup` in my `select` forms, but I keep getting the following error:

```
for inner_val, inner_label in group_items:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I copied and pasted the code straight into my project and even used their provided example:

```
(
    ('Fruits', (
        ('apple', 'Apple'),
        ('peach', 'Peach'),
        ('pear', 'Pear')
    )),
    ('Vegetables', (
        ('cucumber', 'Cucumber'),
        ('potato', 'Potato'),
        ('tomato', 'Tomato'),
    )),
    ('other','None Of The Above')
)
```

but that brings up a different, yet similar error:

```
for item1, item2 in field.choices:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

While looking around SO, I saw things like adding `.iteritems()` to the part after `in`, but since it's a tuple, it was a no-go. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is `group_items`? Setting it equal to the Fruits/Vegetables/other tuple does not result in a `ValueError`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? I have some different code for SelectFields that may be able to help here.

Comment: @Dim Sorry, I'm not too sure what group_items is. I looked in google for code that allowed me to use optgroups in my selects and literally copy-pasted it and followed their usage guidelines. How would I set it equal to the optgroup tuple? To Vasili: I'm trying to add optgroup to my select dropdown since wtform doesn't provide such an option. If your code can handle that, I'd like to see it please.

Comment: @Vasili Is your SelectField code applicable to my situation?

Comment: Ok I just figured out what you are trying to do (I didn't know what OptGroups were previously)... This is 'supposed' to be natively supported, but I can't get it to work either... My code is not relevant in this case, I've never used optgroups.

Comment: @user2986242 did you figure this out? I'm looking to incorporate `<optgroup>`'s into my WTForm as well